# knife search node platform on windows and mac

Tags: chef-infra

I'm running chef 12, on ubuntu 14.04

When I run a **knife node show -l "nodename"** on a mac the platform attribute  comes back with  **mac_os_x 10.10.3**, **mac_os_x 10.8.4** etc. When I run this on the windows machines they all return **windows 6.1.7601**.  I don't see the attribute that shows its a 64bit or 32bit.

When I run  a **knife search node "name:*" -a platform**   I only get mac_os_x no version number. Windows just returns windows My plan is to get all the OS versions of all the nodes.

When I run the same on a windows machines they all come back with the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`knife node show -l` returns all attributes. Just look for the right key, how about the 'kernel.machine' value?

`knife node show 'nodename' -a 'kernel.machine'`